# Ruby on rails Spree and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having a difficult time connecting Amazon S3 buckets to a e-commerce spree application. I have added the necessary code to the initializer/spree.rb and set the necessary environment variables. This is the code inside my spree.rb

```
# Configure Solidus Preferences
# See http://docs.solidus.io/Spree/AppConfiguration.html for details

Spree.config do |config|
  # Without this preferences are loaded and persisted to the database. This
  # changes them to be stored in memory.
  # This will be the default in a future version.
  config.use_static_preferences!

  # Core:

  # Default currency for new sites
  config.currency = "USD"

  # from address for transactional emails
  config.mails_from = "expressmobiletechs@gmail.com"

  # Uncomment to stop tracking inventory levels in the application
  # config.track_inventory_levels = false

  # When set, product caches are only invalidated when they fall below or rise
  # above the inventory_cache_threshold that is set. Default is to invalidate cache on
  # any inventory changes.
  # config.inventory_cache_threshold = 3


  # Frontend:


  config.logo = "logo.jpg"
  config.admin_interface_logo = "logo.jpg"

  # Template to use when rendering layout
  # config.layout = "spree/layouts/spree_application"


  # Admin:

  # Custom logo for the admin
  # config.admin_interface_logo = "logo/solidus_logo.png"

  # Gateway credentials can be configured statically here and referenced from
  # the admin. They can also be fully configured from the admin.
  #
  # config.static_model_preferences.add(
  #   Spree::Gateway::StripeGateway,
  #   'stripe_env_credentials',
  #   secret_key: ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'],
  #   publishable_key: ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  #   server: Rails.env.production? ? 'production' : 'test',
  #   test_mode: !Rails.env.production?
  # )
end

Spree::Frontend::Config.configure do |config|
  config.use_static_preferences!

  config.locale = 'en'
end

Spree::Backend::Config.configure do |config|
  config.use_static_preferences!

  config.locale = 'en'
end

Spree::Api::Config.configure do |config|
  config.use_static_preferences!

  config.requires_authentication = true
end


Spree.user_class = "Spree::LegacyUser"

attachment_config = {

  s3_credentials: {
    access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    bucket:            ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
  },

  storage:        :s3,
  s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
  s3_protocol:    "https",
  bucket:         ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  url:            ":s3_domain_url",

  styles: {
      mini:     "48x48>",
      small:    "100x100>",
      product:  "240x240>",
      large:    "600x600>"
  },

  path:           "/spree/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  default_url:    "/spree/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  default_style:  "product"
}

attachment_config.each do |key, value|
  Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value
end
```

[image]

I am trying to get my spree stores image uploading for products to work with s3. No other discussion on stack has been able to help me.